# Json and XML Webservice in javaFx

Tags: javafx

1. I m new in Javafx Can we implement JSON and XML web service in Javafx?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

JavaFX is just Java and there are many Java libraries for producing and consuming json and xml web services.

The [Jersey Client](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html) and the [RestEasy Client](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html) are some example client APIs appropriate for use in a JavaFX program for consumption of restful json or xml based web services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataFX for this issue: http://www.javafxdata.org/
Here are some tutorials:

- http://jaxenter.com/getting-real-world-data-into-java-ui-controls-with-datafx-46600.html
  http://fxapps.blogspot.de/2012/01/show-data-in-javafx-is-made-easy-by.html